# add products dropdown to oppurtunity module in suitecrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to add products dropdown to the opurtunities module in suitecrm.

Tried adding relationships "one to many, and many to many". Also tried adding dropdown with products. But it shows irrelevant options in the dropdown.

I am trying to achieve the products created in the "products module" to be shown in the dropdown.

I have tried googling/reading the documentation. But am unable to find any thing on this.

Any help or guide with this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was some issue with the installation installation.

got it working with,

1) adding a relation between opportunity and products 
2) adding a relate field to products 
3) create a dynamic drop down field with product

Comment: I got the first two steps working, but don't see how to populate the dynamic drop down with the product. When working in an opportunity, I can click on the 'relate' field that opens up a pop up window where I can select a product, but not a drop down. 

The only things I see related to products in dropdown are product_code, product_type (not the right one), and product_quote. 

How did you get your products to populate a dropdown?